# Opencl: Copying from __constant to __global memory

Tags: opencl, intel, nvidia

I have two kernels (both of them runs only once, so the globalWorkSize is 1 in the example):

The first kernel (`kernel_Calc()`) calculates some values and stores them in the `__global` memory. In this example it calculates (sets the transformation matrix which translates a point in 3D space) a transformation matrix and transforms the origo.

```
inline 
float4 mul( const float4 M[ 4 ], const float4 v)
{
   float4 r;
   r.x = dot( v, M[ 0 ] );
   r.y = dot( v, M[ 1 ] );
   r.z = dot( v, M[ 2 ] );
   r.w = dot( v, M[ 3 ] );
   return r;
}

__kernel
void kernel_Calc( __global float4* g_TransformationMatrices, __global float3* g_Point3D )
{
    __private float4 transformationMatrix[ 4 ];

    transformationMatrix [ 0 ] = (float4) ( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    transformationMatrix [ 1 ] = (float4) ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f );
    transformationMatrix [ 2 ] = (float4) ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    transformationMatrix [ 3 ] = (float4) ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    g_TransformationMatrices[ 0 ] = transformationMatrix[ 0 ];
    g_TransformationMatrices[ 1 ] = transformationMatrix[ 1 ];
    g_TransformationMatrices[ 2 ] = transformationMatrix[ 2 ];
    g_TransformationMatrices[ 3 ] = transformationMatrix[ 3 ];


    float4 point4D = (float4) ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    float4 point4DTransformed = mul( transformationMatrix, point4D);

    g_Point3D[ 0 ] = (float3) ( point4DTransformed.x / point4DTransformed.w ,
                                point4DTransformed.y / point4DTransformed.w ,
                                point4DTransformed.z / point4DTransformed.w );
}
```

On the host side I copy the calculated `__global` buffers into `__constant` buffers (`CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` buffers) with `clEnqueueCopyBuffer()` function. (I do this because I hope read from the `__constant` memory will be faster than read from the `__global` memory. The buffer copy can be done on the device side with this function without copy the `__global` back to the host and then copy it into the `__constant`.)

The second kernel (`kernel_Test()`) tries to load the calculated values into a `__global` variable (`__global float4* test`) which can be read on the host side. The `sizeStruct` is a user defined struct which contains only an integer (this is the number of the matrices and transformed points). The second and the third parameters are the buffers in the `__constant` memory which were filled up with `clEnqueueCopyBuffer()` function.

```
struct sizeStruct
{
    int m_Size;
};

__kernel 
void kernel_Test( __constant struct sizeStruct* c_SS,
                  __constant float4* c_TransformationMatrices,
                  __constant float3* c_Points3D,
                  __global float4 *test )
{                   
    test[ 0 ] = c_TransformationMatrices[ 0 ];
    test[ 1 ] = c_TransformationMatrices[ 1 ];
    test[ 2 ] = c_TransformationMatrices[ 2 ];
    test[ 3 ] = c_TransformationMatrices[ 3 ];
}
```

The problem is when I run the program the test variable contains this:

```
1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
```

but it should contain:

```
1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

I checked the `__constant` variables (by copying them to the host memory) they contain the correct data. The code is a simplified version of my program. That is the reason it may contain unnecessary operations and parameters. The example is tested and works as I described.

More interesting when I change `__constant float3* c_Points3D` kernel parameter to `__global float3* c_Points3D` kernel parameter (but still use the read_only buffer which were filled up with `clEnqueueCopyBuffer()` function) it works fine. It also works when I remove the `__constant struct sizeStruct* c_SS` parameter.
So it seems something is wrong with the address spaces of the arguments of the kernel_Test but the problem appears at `__constant` -> `__global` copy.

I’m running the program on nvidia geforce gtx 690 but I can change the device (and the platform) to intel i7-3930k (using intel sdk). Using intel-i7 cpu everything works fine without any change in the kernel code.

**Q1:** Why does this weird behaviour appear? Does anybody have an idea what am I doing wrong?

**Q2:** Is it legal to create a buffer with `cl_mem_read_only` and use with `__global` address space qualifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q1**: Why does this weird behaviour appear? Does anybody have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Nothing obvious comes to mind, can you post a complete minimum working example that compiles on Windows?  I'd like to test on AMD Radeon GPUs.

> **Q2:** Is it legal to create a buffer with cl_mem_read_only and use with __global address space qualifier?

Yes that is legal, although you will want to add `const` to specify that the buffer is read-only, see section 6.5.1 of the OpenCL 1.2 specification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I uploaded the test project (VS2010) here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23471668/OpenCLConstantTest.zip

Comment: Your code works correctly on my AMD Radeon HD 6970.  I'll test on some Nvidia cards a little later.

Comment: NVIDIA cards have terrible support for vectors in OpenCL, the float4 is probably the root cause of the issue.  The same happens with AMDs FFT implementation, they use float2 and the code works fine on Intel CPUs and AMD GPUs, but not on NVIDIA cards.